# Import Google Admin User report to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to import the User Report in a Google Admin account into Google Sheets. It is straightforward to export to a Google Sheet, but I would like to run a Google script that will pull in the User Report into an existing Google Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function cloneGoogleSheet(existingSheet, userReportSheet){
   //get source google sheet document
   var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(userReportSheet);
   //get the source sheet on document
   var sourceSheet = source.getSheetByName('NameOfSheet');

   //get data range 
   var dataRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();

   // get A1 notation for the range identification
   var A1Range = dataRange.getA1Notation();

   //get data within the specified range
   var data = dataRange.getValues();

   //specify the existing spreadsheet you want to pull data to
   var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById(existingSheet);

   //target sheet on your existing document 
   var targetSheet = target.getSheetByName('NameOfTargetSheet');

   //if there is already data on the target sheet, you may want to remove it 
   targetSheet.clear({contentsOnly: true});

   //now you set the target range of the values you get from your user report
   targetSheet.getRange(A1Range).setValues(data);
};
```